# в чём смысл строки $productParamIds = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$productParamIds);

Tags: php

$productParamIds - простой массив с айдишниками

```
Array
(
    [Цвет] => Array
        (
            [0] => 141627
            [1] => 141631
            [2] => 141638
            [3] => 141640
            [4] => 141645
            [5] => 141655
            [6] => 141656
            [7] => 141657
            [8] => 141658
            [9] => 141671
            [10] => 141674
            [11] => 141675
            .....
        )
)
```

есть строка кода

```
 $productParamIds = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$productParamIds);
```

1. `call_user_func_array` — Вызывает callback-функцию с массивом параметров. Зачем нужна эта функция? Почему не написать просто:

   $productParamIds = array_intersect($productParamIds);
2. `array_intersect` - вычисляет схождение массивов. Почему ей передаётся всего один массив? Схождение с чем ей надо вычислить?

Какова логика этого кода и что он делает?

Comment: Прочитайте ещё раз что делает call_user_func_array

Comment: Вызывает функцию и передаёт ей параметры

Comment: Ещё раз перечитайте примеры и подумайте чем они отличаются от обычного вызова функции

Comment: А какой именно массив лежит в `$productParamIds` имеется возможность чекнуть?

Comment: конечно же я читал перед тем как спросить :) разница в том, что call_user_func_array вызывает функцию внутри себя. Правда я не понимаю, какой положительный эффект от этого достигается, учитываю то, что по форумам пишут о явной тормознутости этой функции.

Comment: Посмотрите, чем друг от друга отличаются `call_user_func` и `call_user_func_array()` Есть у меня подозрение что $productParamIds имеет два индекса первого уровня ('Цвет' и еще что-то). Соответственно массив под первым индексом станет первым параметром, а второй - вторым параметром. В любом случае данный код стОит переписать

Comment: все же... мой вопрос состоит из двух частей. На вторую более или менее косвенный ответ дан. По поводу первой части вопроса может есть соображения? В чём положительный эффект от работы с функцией call_user_func_array()? почему не вызывают сразу нужную функцию, а вызывают внутри call_user_func_array() ?

Comment: Боюсь что положительного эффека по такому небольшому куску кода не увидеть. Если в массиве всегда два неизменных ключа, то с этим вызовом сильно перемудрили и стОит это переписать как минимум на `$ids = array_intersect($productParamIds['Цвет'], $productParamIds['Другой ключ']);`

Comment: "Какова логика этого кода и что он делает?" Для ответа на этот вопрос нужен контекст гораздо шире

Answer (score 0):

```
    $productParamIds = [
        [1,2,3,4,5],
        [1,2,3,4,6]
    ];

    $productParamIds = call_user_func_array ('array_intersect', $productParamIds);
```

В данном случае, это будет корректный код, что именно вас удивляет?

Comment: вопросы не связаны с удивлением, они связаны с непониманием сути происходящего. Тем более, что в документаци https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect.php указано, что array_intersect принимает 2 и более массивов, а не 1 многомерный, пример которого вы приводите. Поэтому вряд ли это будет корректный код.

Answer (score 0):

Код проверяет схождение массивов. `array_intersect` - сличает массивы. Ей необходимо передать сличаемые массивы через запятую: array_intersect($ar1,$ar2,$ar3..).  Эти сличаемые массивы представлены как элементы имеющегося массива. `call_user_func_array` - функция, которая позволяет передать в первый свой параметр (в функцию `array_intersect) переменное число аргументов, которые являются элементами массива из второго аргумента.

Вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090215/%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0) наглядный пример и наглядное объяснение.