# сравнение элементов одномерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Вроде задача простая, но не осилил. Есть массив

```
Array
(
    [Размер, см] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2236
            [1] => 2421
            [2] => 6317
            [3] => 6331
            [4] => 6338
            [5] => 6345
        )

    [Цвет] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4305
            [1] => 4325
            [2] => 11837

        )

    [Материал] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2141
            [1] => 2148
            [2] => 2155
            [3] => 2161
            [4] => 2168

        )

    [Количество, шт] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15021
            [1] => 15042
            [2] => 15049
        )

)
```

количество ключей заранее не известно. Надо сравнить подмассивы (размер, цвет, материал...) и выявить одинаковые, имеющиеся во всех подмассивах значения.

Есть функция `array_intersect($ar1,$ar2,$ar3,$ar4);` которая работает и всё хорошо. Но плохо то, что ей надо передать массивы, через запятую, количество которых я заранее не могу знать.

попробовал вот такой финт ушами

```
// разделяю на отдельные массивы
foreach ($paramIds as $array) {
   foreach ($array as $j => $val) {
       ${"array{$j}"}[] = $val;
   }
}
//передаю их в функцию сравнения
$res = array_intersect(${"array{$j}"});
```

не работает и интуитивно понимаю, что не должно бы. Как бы разделить массив на подмассивы - просто, сделать их сличение просто, то соединить задачу в кучу не просто. Плиз, хелп.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: а можно подробнее? я как раз по этой функции вопрос вчера написал, не понимая её сути

Comment: она вызывает функцию из первого аргумента передавая ей переменное число аргументов, которые представлены элементами массива во втором аргументе

Comment: т.е. в данном случае код call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$paramIds); должно быть решением. Спасибо!

Comment: `array_intersect(...array_values($arr))`